# make command not tabbing to complete file names

Tags: linux, makefile, compilation, command

Trying to use the 'make' command in linux to compile c programs for class. If I do make  it works, but if I type 'make' and then start typing the file name and tab it doesn't autocomplete the file for me. It's kind of annoying and I'd like to be able to use it instead of typing gcc -o   everytime to test my program. How can I fix this?

*edit*
I have GalliumOS - 2.0 (ubuntu 16.04) fully installed on a c720 chromebook (ChromeOS has been completely removed and replaced with this)
The shell is bash.

*edit2*
adding the line `complete -f -X '!*' make` in my ~/.bashrc file works, but now I need help making it ignore directories or make it so that only .c and compiled c programs are added to the autocomplete.

Comment: `make` is a build manager. The purpose of a build manager is basically to allow you to build your application without calling the compiler yourself and without specifying all your files in the command line. Read `make` documentation and look at the examples to learn how to use it. With a good Makefile, all you have to do is to type the `make all` command, and your program will be built, no matter how many files you have.

Comment: Tab completion is a feature your shell, not of `make`. At the very minimum, you should indicate your shell (on Linux, usually Bash) but ideally, also show a basic understanding of how to diagnose at least simple problems in its configuration. In Bash, it is highly likely that your distro includes third-party tab completion modules, so we really need to know what's installed on your system in order to even begin to troubleshoot this. Please [edit] your question to include these details.

Answer (score 0):

It probably does not complete, because the parameter following `make` is usually the name of the target (for the recipe) and not a filename.

It perhaps completes for options that expect a filename, like e.g. `make -f mymakefile`.

Comment: When I was running ubuntu 12.04 with crouton through ChromeOS it was working fine which is why I'm confused as to why it isn't working now with a full linux install.

Comment: It might be because the new completion function is context-aware. It let's you complete what is appropriate there. My zsh completion looks inside the `Makefile` for target names, too.